# Condition failing even if the array values are empty

Tags: php

I have a piece of code where the condition fails even when the array is empty.
This is the code:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES['jform']['name']['gallery']);
```

which outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

This is the condition:

```
$galfile = $_FILES['jform']['name']['gallery'];
if(!empty($galfile))
{
    //do something
}
```

It should fail, but the program enters the `if` block. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see your array is not empty it has a blank element.

The work around is [array_filte](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)r which will eliminate blank data

```
$array = array(0=>'');
$array1 = array_filter($array);

print_r($array1);

if(!empty($array1)){
  echo "has elememt";
}else{
    echo "empty";
}
```

This is what u need

**UPDATE**

What if the value contains multiple spaces, yes this could be handled using a call back function

```
$array1 = array_filter($array,"call_back_function");
function call_back_function($val){
    return trim($val);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the element is **''** - it could be a couple of spaces, too!? And why are you filtering a value - there might be a reason for it to be there!

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the print_r() the array is NOT empty - it has one element, which on the other side looks like white space or empty.

**Update**

I would recommend reading **[POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)**, where you'll learn that `name` is the original name of the file and `tmp_name` is a random name of the temporary file, that has been just uploaded.

According to my experience you should check the **[Error Messages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)**.

The check you're interested is:

```
foreach ( array_keys( $_FILES['jform']['gallery'] ) AS $key ) {
    if ( UPLOAD_ERR_OK == $_FILES['jform']['gallery']['error'][$key] ) {
        // do the stuff with the uploaded file in $_FILES['jform']['gallery']['tmp_name'][$key]
    }
}
```

Keep an eye on the names of the arrays where `gallery` is before `name`.

Comment: So how do i overcome this??

Comment: <input type="file" multiple="" class="inputbox" value="" id="jform_gallery" name="jform[gallery][]" aria-invalid="false"> This is the input box.

Comment: @amit - What is the output of *print_r($_FILES['jform']['gallery']['name']);*

Answer (score 1):

In your case print_r() told you that `galfile == array('') // 1 element is in the array`

According to the [documentaion](http://pt2.php.net/empty) only `array() // 0 elements` is considered empty. So the if statement is executed correctly.

In your case you should write:

```
$galfile = $_FILES['jform']['name']['gallery'];
if(!empty($galfile) && !empty($galfile[0]) )
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you working with arrays, before checking for empty you can sanitize your array using [array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) or the similar functions:

```
$galfile = array_filter($_FILES['jform']['name']['gallery']);
if(!empty($galfile))
{
    //do something
}
```

But when you use global array _FILES, more correctly is checks for error:

```
if($_FILES['jform']['error']['gallery'] == 0)
{
    //do something
}
```

P.S. If you want to filtering all array elements, you can use [filter_var_array](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var-array.php)